# How to connect GSM modem with online server?

Tags: server, at-command, modem, ussd

What I am trying to do is setup gsm modem and online server, so that when  the server makes a request(using AT commands) to get the remaining balance of the modem's sim, the modem would run a ussd code and send the results back to the server(it runs 24/7). But I don't know how modems could create a connection with a server without being connected to a pc. I need help?

Comment: What modem model are you using? Internet connectivity is usually supported through custom commands, different from model to model. Anyway you need an host to send AT commands (a PC or an host micro). You cannot send AT commands "from server"; you send them through a serial device (RS232 or USB).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But i need it to run 24/7. How can I do that if it is plugged in to a pc that will eventually shutdown. Is there any other way to make a ussd request and get the response of a particular SIM balance from a server?

Comment: Your question is too broad. I suggest defining your setup hardware and then coming back with a more specific question. What needs to be clear is: what is going to send AT commands to your GSM module? An Arduino? Or it is a custom application stored in the module itself? What model are you using? What vendor? If there's an application in nuce could you update you question with its relevant parts?

Comment: Basically, I am planning to build a mobile payment system using mobile airtime. So when users make a payment, I want to confirm the transaction by automatically asking the remaining balance on my SIM(money receiver). I am planning to use Huawei E220 USB GSM modem. The vendor is ethiotelecom. The AT commands are going to be sent from custom application stored in the modem. I will have a serverside softwre code stored in remote server. And when certain conditions are met I want the server to make a request to get the remaining balance of the sim on the module.